# Can we resize the dotted size on dotted borders?

Tags: css

I was wondering if it's possible without using images to make the dots bigger on a border in CSS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
div
{
    border: 10px dotted #000000;
}
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7HTd/

Comment: It would be beneficial to note that you're using shorthand notation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible using the `border-width` property. The demo below applies this using shorthand notation.

### [See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TrvjK/)